# Calling a jQuery function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to import a `.csv` file in my JavaScript and trying to save it in an array.
I got the below sample while searching on stackoverflow.com to use  `jQuery-CSV` library's function called `csv2Dictionary()` to do so.

```
var data = $.csv2Dictionary(csv):
```

In above line of code "data" will give me my array, but can some one help me know before I get to this step, how can I call `csv2Dictionary()` from my JavaScript?

Comment: Above code is `javascript` and calls `csv2Dictionary`. Sounds like you've got what you want?

Comment: You can directly call it without any problems. jQuery is a framework that just gives an easier way of writing Javascript code.

Comment: that line is javascript, just use it like that. But make sure you have included the library (jQuery-CSV) you are using

Comment: If you meant call it, without using jQuery, just javascript, you can't, you need to have jQuery loaded.  Otherwise as stated, jQuery *is* javascript, just a framework built on it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean "call it from my javascript"?

The answer is easy: **do it** ;)

Just make sure that jQuery and jQuery-CSV are loaded before you try to call the function. Then  you can easily do something like this:

```
var csv;
// ...
// Create your CSV
// ...
$.csv2Dictionary(csv);
```

Comment: Well my real concern is that I have my data in say data.csv file. How do I put the data in var csv so that when the jquery function $.csv2Dictionary(csv) is called it knows which data to be modified? I hope I am not confusing you all further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, you want to access the File on your Computer via Javascript? Maybe you can use the Javascript File API, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Maybe this little tutorial can help you: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

```
    readTheFileWhenLoaded = function(){
        $('#inputTypeFileInHTML').change(function(event){
            readTheFile(this.files[0]);
            $('#inputTypeFileInHTML').val(null);
        });
    }

     readTheFile= function(file){
        var fileContent;
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
              fileContent= e.target.result;
              fileContentAsStringJavaScriptVar(fileContent);
          }
          r.readAsText(file);
    }

    fileContentAsStringJavaScriptVar= function(fileContent){
        console.log(fileContent);
         $.csv2Dictionary(fileContent);
    }
```